# What is good practice in storing and accessing data locally in a javascript web application?

Tags: javascript, json

Context: I'm building a simple website based on colouring in different countries on an SVG world map. For now, everything is just running locally, I have an index.html, an app.js file in which I've built a bunch of functions. But I'm really confused about where I should store data and how I should access it.

For example, I need to have a list of all the countries stored somewhere as an array, which can be read into a function in app.js, and used. I thought this was the kind of thing that a JSON array is perfect for, but it seems you can't just access a local JSON file, it has to be requested from a web server? I could just paste in the array as a global variable at the top of app.js, but that's supposed to be bad practice.

Should I have a separate data.js file which is called as a script somewhere? Or do I need to start using a database and learn some SQL?

Comment: If you just need it in the app, and it's a simple app, you can certainly just store as variable in app js. It wouldn't need to be json, it would just be a normal javascript object. No need for storage solutions if it doesn't need to persist.

Comment: You could also do as you said, just have a separate js file with a var that holds this data if you wanted to keep things separate. That would be the same as a global variable, but more organized.

Comment: Does the information need to persist in between a single person's visits? If it does, and it is on a per-person basis, LocalStorage would be a good approach. If it's just for during the visit you don't need to store it anywhere.

Comment: If you do want to use JSON, you can also run a local web server. Python has a built in one with `python -m http.server`, or if you prefer node there's the http-server package which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Either get them from an API (yours or someone else's) or store them in your web page (perhaps as a sourced JavaScript file). Update the source when the list of countries changes (it doesn't happen all that often). There are various APIs available to get lists of countries and country data, for example [RestCountries](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all).

if you want to store things locally that the user creates e.g. to operate offline or across browser sessions then see [Web Storage Overview](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage) for options.